# Laravel package config file override/cascade

Tags: laravel, package, overriding, config, cascade

I am trying to use a config file I had published from a package I'm using (andrewelkins/cabinet) in order to override the vendor's default config file.

Location of *my config file* (the file I intend to override the default with):

```
app/config/packages/andrewelkins/cabinet/config.php
```

Location of the *andrewelkins/cabinet* default config file (which I would like to override with the former):

```
vendor/andrewelkins/cabinet/src/config.php
```

Am I required to specify the location of my overriding config file somewhere? My initial understanding was that config files automatically cascade based on the folder/filenames, but my experience so far seems to indicate that I need to specify that I would like to override the vendor's config file.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has the same issue, I solved this by extending the class I wanted to use from the package, `CabinetUpload`, and in it's constructor, called the parent constructor and then added the namespace of (my) package, and where it should look for the configs:

```
public function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();
   Config::addNamespace('administration', 'andrewelkins/cabinet');
}
```